# Setting path directories for running files using command, python filename.py

Tags: python, macos, path, pythonpath

I have added directories to `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` in an attempt to run programs from directories other than my home directory (platform Mac OS X).

I have added a `PYTHONPATH` that allows me to import the target file when I am signed into the python interactive prompt.

I have the file I wish to open in a directory that is listed when I type at the command line.

```
echo $PATH
```

The directory with the target file is also listed when I type `sys.path` into the interactive prompt

Still it won't open at the command line when I type…

```
My-Macbook-Pro:~homedirectory$ python filename.py
```

Is there another environmental variable that I need to update somewhere?  Other suggestions of why this isn't working?

I hope I have provided enough detail. New to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding directories to the `$PATH` environment variable won't enable you to do `python filename.py` from anywhere. The `$PATH` is used to find executable files, such as the `python` executable. And files you want to pass as arguments will still need to be in the working directory.

Alternatively, you can make your python scripts executable. Here's how.

1) If you put the following shebang line on the first line of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

2) Give your script executable permissions, like so.

```
chmod +x YOUR_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py
```

3) Now, if your python script is in your `$PATH`, you should be able to run your script like so, and it will automatically run with python because of the shebang line.

```
YOUR_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py
```

Additionally, `$PYTHONPATH` is used to set python module search paths, so it is not useful for this purpose.

Comment: That makes sense, and it works perfectly if I follow your directions.  Thanks.  I still can't run it with command 'python my_python_script.py' without appending the path from the home directory.  I have no reason to NEED to do this, but I am still wondering why.  Thanks again.

Comment: The `$PATH` is the search path for the command line executables. The arguments are relative to the working directory of the binary. Files in the `$PATH` are not accessible from everywhere.